# How to add digital signature with image to PDF files using Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, digital-signature

I am working on a script that adds digital signature to PDF files using Perl PDF::API2.

I am using Martin Schuette script from:
https://mschuette.name/files/pdfsign.pl

my problem is that script add a hidden signature and I am trying to add an image that linked to the signature.

I tried to change that part in the code but with no luck:

```perl
# Annotation Widget, contd.
$sigannotdict->{Type}    = PDFName("Annot");
$sigannotdict->{Subtype} = PDFName("Widget");
$sigannotdict->{F}       = PDFNum(4);
$sigannotdict->{Parent}  = $sigformdict;
$sigannotdict->{Rect}    = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Literal->new("[0 0 0 0]");
$sigannotdict->{P}       = $pdf->openpage(1);
$sigannotdict->{H}       = PDFName("N");
$sigannotdict = $p->new_obj($sigannotdict);
```

Comment: The code in the question is identical to the one in the referred to file `pdfsign.pl`. Please show the code that you tried.